# Deployment of the ASP.NET website to Windows Server via FTP

Tags: asp.net, ftp, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my test website to the ftp server, yet I am having quite a few difficulties with it (as it is my very first time doing this).

Here is how the ftp's server folder setup looks like:

There is a main folder named **www_root**, which contains the following two folders **app_data** and **data**.

Here is a printscreen from a **TotalCommander**:

[image]

I was being told by the support people, that I need to copy all my data into the **www_root** folder.

Once I published my ASP.NET 5 MVC application via Visual Studio 2015 to a File System, I could see three folders:

[image]

My base `index.html`, together with **css** & **javascript** is located under **wwwroot** folder. Here is what the inside of **wwwroot** folder looks like:

[image]

When I copy the contents of my **wwwroot** folder inside **www_root** folder (under FTP) and I **exclude** `web.config` file, then my base webpage is loaded without a problem (but without server side logic...it's just a plain page with some HTML & CSS code).

Now the problem occured when I added `web.config` to that folder, then suddenly I received *Error 500* when I tried to open my website. I believed that the problem was caused by the fact that `web.config` contained the following setup:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="..\approot\web.cmd" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="..\logs\stdout.log" startupTimeLimit="3600"></httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here I could see that we are targeting **\approot\web.cmd** file. Therefore what I did was, that I copied my **approot** & **logs** folders (generated by Visual Studio) to the base folder under my FTP.

So in the end when I logged in to my FTP I had the following folders: **approot**, **logs**, **www_root**, where inside of **www_root** I had all my css, js, & index.html.

Nonetheless, when I reloaded my webpage, it still gave me the 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied..

How can I solve this problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is your IIS configured on the server? How is your authentication? Does it allow anonymous access? How is your AppPool configured? What .NET framework do you target?

Comment: Where are you tryin' to deploy you ASP.Net 5 WebSite ? Azure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem was occurred by the fact, that my hosting server had folder named **www_root**, however my ASP.NET application automatically creates folder **wwwrooot**.

What I ended up doing is creating a script, which loops through all the files and replaces **wwwroot** with **www_root**.

That has solved the problem.